# How do you get text from quill delta server side in node js

Tags: node.js, quill

I am using node, express, mongoose,

One of my mongoose schema, call it the Submission schema, has a field called "contents", which contains a quill delta. What I want to do is convert this contents object to text server side. This is part of a standard API endpoint with high volume. It's not a one time piece of migration code for example.

On client side, this is resolved in a standard way: set up a quill editor on an html element, use quill.setContents then quill.getText. But I want to do in the node js server environment.

There are 2 possible solutions I am currently aware of

1. Use JSdom to virtually create html elements in the node js environment and then use the client side method (I believe this is undesirable due to the volume of the endpoint).
2. Call getText on the client side, then send the text as part of the request body (this is what I'm currently doing). It works just fine, but I don't think it's best practice to send these big text files in the request when I could just send the id of the MongoDB object in the request and retrieve it server side.

What I would like to do is have just a function I can call directly on the delta in node to get the text out without having to fiddle with html elements. Any help much appreciated